# Are changes made to files in azure pipeline discarded after pipeline runs?

Tags: azure, yaml, pipeline

Lets say one of the steps is replace content of one file with another file using CmdLine script task in yaml file. After pipeline runs do changes made to that file stick around or are they discarded?

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about hosted runners, the changes will be discarded. If the file is part of your repository, you can check it in within your pipeline to persist the changes.